# ID select of td using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is onLoad essentially, find all id's of each td, that has a number 1-7 and replace it with the image that corresponds with that number i.e.

```
<td id="7" class="level">7</td>
```

would change the 7, the content to ...

```
<td id="7" class="level"><img src="../img/CL7.png" alt=""></td>
```

So what i have so far is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("td").click(function()
        {
            var findID =$(this).attr('id');
            var replace ="<img src=\"../img/cl"+ findID +".png\" alt=''>";
            function ReplaceCellContent(findID, replace)
            {
                return $("tbody tr td.level:contains('" + findID + "')").html(replace);
            }
            var myStringArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
            var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                ReplaceCellContent(findID, replace);
        }
    });
});
```

So it will go, find all of the ID's of the td's onclick of each td. I want it to do this to ALL of the ids ranging from 1-7, when the page loads.

I am somewhat new to JQuery/JavaScript,I DO HAVE THE SCRIPT LINK TO JQUERY API THROUGH GOOGLE FYI, so any explanation would be greatly appreciated as well. I was trying to use the loop at the bottom to loop through all of the possible numbers and just plug them in but i can't think of how to connect each back to of its original td, which had had that ID.

the HTML Table that the JQuery needs to change looks like this, written out:

```
<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Krack</td>
            <td id="7" class="level">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lively</td>
            <td id="6" class="level">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bamon Williams</td>
            <td id="6" class="level">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sinister Char</td>
            <td id="5" class="level">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Senior BoomBox</td>
            <td id="5" class="level">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Blitzking</td>
            <td id="4" class="level">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hadooooken</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jumpman2392</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ALEC*</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Frokido</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B. McOxbig</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[MES] Koko</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PinkStrank</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>papa von</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nuski</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LunchBoxes</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Grenade65</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[MGS]TOAD</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NoahS</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not render the relevant cells with a semantically-named class and supply a data value with the ID? Are number-only IDs even legal IDs (a separate question than whether or not browsers allow their use)?

Comment: Numeric IDs are technically not valid, but will work in most/all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is great, but I don't recommend it for everything and especially not until you really have a good understanding of JavaScript, so this solution only uses jQuery to register a function to be called when the page is ready for interaction:

```
 // When the document is ready, run the following function:
 $(function(){

    // Get all the TD elements:
    var allTheTDs = document.querySelectorAll("td.level");

    // Loop through the array of all the TD elements
    for(var i = 0; i < allTheTDs.length; ++i){

        // Check to see if the current TD has an ID of 7 or less
        if(allTheTDs[i].id <=7 ){

           // Remove the current content of the TD
           allTheTDs[i].innerHTML = "";

           // Create a new img element
           var img = document.createElement("img");

           // Configure the new img element to have a src attribute value
           // that is based on the id value
           img.src = "../img/CL" + allTheTDs[i].id + ".png";

           // Give the img an alt to match the src, just to show
           // it works
           img.alt = "../img/CL" + allTheTDs[i].id + ".png";

           // Append the new image into the current TD
           allTheTDs[i].appendChild(img);
        }
    }
 });
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96hkhy4j/4/

Comment: can the querySelectorALL select a td with a class? like i have level as a class?

Comment: Yes, any valid CSS selector can be used. Just pass ".className" to the function.

Comment: No, it would be td.level  I've adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: ok thnak you, it doesnt seem to be changing the numbers to images when i put it in the index.php, any idea?

Comment: It shouldn't be changing numbers, but it will create new image elements and insert them into the td elements.

Comment: @Apparatus17 Did you try my updated code? Just had to fix a small typo. Try out the fiddle.

Comment: yes it works well, i like how it is tep by step layed out, i do have another issue if you would be willing to help?

Comment: @Apparatus17 Yes, go ahead and don't forget to up vote the answer. :)

Comment: OK so i am also using a mostly jquery sort function that allows someone to click on a th and sorts that row, what happens when i have have an image tag in there is that it will sort based on something of the image and not any type of id, its written in javascript.jquery and was wondering if you could help or add any insight?

Comment: How about you post a new question and let me know (here) when you've posted it. That way, the community can pitch in to help you.

Comment: i have to wait the 90 minutes to ask another question but i believe i explained it well in my draft it shoul donly be a few more minutes

Comment: Ok, well, I've got to hit the hay now. But, I will check in the AM and if it's not answered by then, I'll give it a crack.

Comment: fair enough thank you and everyoen else for all of their help, i really appriciate the guiding.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958045/jquery-table-sorting-not-working-with-images) here is the new question, i have to work til 6pm est i will be back after that

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myStringArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  for (var i = 1; i <= myStringArray.length; i++) {
    var findID = i;
    var replace ="<img src=\"../img/cl"+ findID +".png\" alt=''>";
    ReplaceCellContent(findID, replace);
  }
  function ReplaceCellContent(findID, replace) {
    return $("tbody tr td.level:contains('" + findID + "')").html(replace);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Krack</td>
            <td id="7" class="level">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lively</td>
            <td id="6" class="level">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bamon Williams</td>
            <td id="6" class="level">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sinister Char</td>
            <td id="5" class="level">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Senior BoomBox</td>
            <td id="5" class="level">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Blitzking</td>
            <td id="4" class="level">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hadooooken</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jumpman2392</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ALEC*</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Frokido</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B. McOxbig</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[MES] Koko</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PinkStrank</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>papa von</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nuski</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LunchBoxes</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Grenade65</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[MGS]TOAD</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NoahS</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: yes that would do what i was looking can you explain a bit on the javascript part though?

Comment: this works very well, my only problem is the sort function i am using for the table sees the mages differnetly then the numbers, so instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc its more like 2,6,4,1,3,5 etc, Any ideas on how to still keep that number around some how...?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Based on which column are you sorting ? Name or Level ? And is sorting done after loading the images ?

Comment: sorting is done after the Queryis selected from the DB and displayed (PHP) and then it is displayed as a number, i thought it would be easier to just display the image out of the db like so`<td id=".$copLevel." class=\"level\"><img src='img/cl".$copLevel.".png' alt=''></td>` which is why I thought maybe it would be better if it was done after it was loaded in

Comment: but it still does the same thing where it will not put the images in the right order, but it does it right when they are only integers

Answer (score 1):

Just replace line 3 with this..

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("tbody td").each(function()
        {
            var findID =$(this).attr('id');
            var replace ="<img src=\"../img/cl"+ findID +".png\" alt=''>";
            function ReplaceCellContent(findID, replace)
            {
                return $("tbody tr td.level:contains('" + findID + "')").html(replace);
            }
            var myStringArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
            var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                ReplaceCellContent(findID, replace);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this works just as well and is very similar to my original code thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just add jQuery and try this way

```
<script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('table tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
        var id =$(this).attr('id');
        $(this).html('<img src="../img/CL'+id+'.png" alt="">')


});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what i was trying to accomplish, i was changing a number in a img using that same number as an identifier to have it be changed.

Comment: Ohh sorry Apparatus17   you just replace this line  $(this).html('<img src="../img/CL'+id+'.png" alt="">')