# Jquery Table sorting not working with images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table being echo'ed out by php,

```
<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Krack</td>
            <td id="7" class="level">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lively</td>
            <td id="6" class="level">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bamon Williams</td>
            <td id="6" class="level">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sinister Char</td>
            <td id="5" class="level">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Senior BoomBox</td>
            <td id="5" class="level">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Blitzking</td>
            <td id="4" class="level">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hadooooken</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jumpman2392</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ALEC*</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Frokido</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B. McOxbig</td>
            <td id="2" class="level">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[MES] Koko</td>
            <td id="1" class="level">1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Then `<td id="1" class="level">1</td>` are being changed by some javascript to have images  in place of the '1'.

When the user clicks on one of the th, Pplayer Name or Level, it will sort that column in descending or ascending order, but the catch is when I go to sort the the Level column when it consists of images , it will jumble the images and they will not be in the right order (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 more like 5,6,2,7,3,1,4) The JQuery function does work with integers and normal strings but i do not know how it sorts or deals with image tags

The link for the javascript library is [here](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a new version of the last question's answer that includes a solution for this new problem available at: https://jsfiddle.net/mdbdj895/1/

This causes the `<td>` elements that contain the pictures to get a sorttable_customkey attribute with appropriate value (based on the `<td>`'s `id` attribute), since the library you are using seems to need that attribute.

The result now is that, not only do images get created in the `<td>` elements that have a `src` that is based on the parent `<td>`'s id attribute, but that `<td>` itself gets the new attribute with correct value, like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Krack</td>
    <td id="7" class="level" sorttable_customkey="7">
      <img src="../img/CL7.png" alt="7">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ok just got home, so it would be a simple as me adding a atrribute to my php echo and giving it the id of the level?

Comment: @Marcus Scott WOW this was even simpler then i thought it would be thank you for takign a look at the script, next i need to learn more javascript

Comment: From what I understand about the sortable library you are using, the element you want to sort on just needs this `sortable_customkey` attribute with a value that it knows how to sort on. My code generates the attribute and the value (based on the level specified by the `id` attribute), but it doesn't matter how the attribute gets there with its value (you could generate it from .php).

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at that library and it seems you have to use [custom keys](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#customkeys)

It would be this way:

```
<td id="1" class="level" sorttable_customkey="1">1</td>
<td id="2" class="level" sorttable_customkey="2">2</td>
<td id="3" class="level" sorttable_customkey="3">3</td>
.................. And so on
```